# How does vala allow defining GObjects with no default constructor?

Tags: vala, gobject

The Vala [tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial) shows that classes can be written with constructors either in GObject style, or in a style similar to Java / C# etc.

<del>The tutorial shows that this is completely independent of whether the class inherits from Glib.GObject or not.</del> (EDIT: I was confused by the tutorial switching between `Glib.Object` and `Object`.  In Vala there's an implicit `using Glib`, so the two are the same).

Am I right in thinking that if a Glib.GObject subclass is defined without a default constructor (using Java/C# style), an implicit default constructor will have to be defined for GObject, presumably leaving all fields filled with binary zero (as per GObject initialization)?

See also [Initialize a GObject with parameters which are not GObject properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777869/initialize-a-gobject-with-parameters-which-are-not-gobject-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vala will automatically create a constructor in the C code. This follows the *_new naming pattern. So the simplest example:

```
void main () {
    new ExampleWithoutExplicitConstructor ();
}

class ExampleWithoutExplicitConstructor {
}
```

If you compile this with `valac --ccode example.vala` and look at the resulting C code you will see `_vala_main` calls `example_without_explicit_constructor_new ()` and this then calls `example_without_explicit_constructor_construct ()`. `example_without_explicit_constructor_construct ()` then calls `g_object_new ()` for that type. As part of `g_object_new` creating the type it will call `example_without_explicit_constructor_instance_init ()` where any variables can be initialized.

Here is a more complex example that inherits from `Object`, so is a full `GObject` class, has a field with a default value and a property with a default value:

```
void main () {
    new ExampleWithoutExplicitConstructor ();
}

class ExampleWithoutExplicitConstructor:Object {
    private string example_field = "default";

    public string an_object_property { get; 
        set; 
        default = "this object properties default string";
        }
}
```

You will notice from the C code that the `_new`, `_construct`, `g_object_new`, `_instance_init` pattern is the same. What Vala has done is set the `_instance_init` to initialize the default values for the fields and properties.

Public fields without default values are null. You will see they appear in the definition of the `struct` that holds the instance data. Private fields are similar, but held in a private `struct` for the instance. You can see this for yourself by playing around with the example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out with `valac -C`.

Example code:

```
class MySuper : Object
{
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public MySuper (int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
        j = 1;
    }
}

class MyDerived : MySuper
{
    public MyDerived ()
    {
        base (10);
    }
}
```

The (relevant parts of the) generated C code looks like this:

```
MySuper* my_super_construct (GType object_type, gint i) {
    MySuper * self = NULL;
    gint _tmp0_ = 0;
    self = (MySuper*) g_object_new (object_type, NULL);
    _tmp0_ = i;
    self->priv->i = _tmp0_;
    self->priv->j = 1;
    return self;
}


MySuper* my_super_new (gint i) {
    return my_super_construct (TYPE_MY_SUPER, i);
}


MyDerived* my_derived_construct (GType object_type) {
    MyDerived * self = NULL;
    self = (MyDerived*) my_super_construct (object_type, 10);
    return self;
}


MyDerived* my_derived_new (void) {
    return my_derived_construct (TYPE_MY_DERIVED);
}
```

Some ovservations of what valac generates:

- MySuper and MyDerived both get a `_construct` and `_new` function.
- `my_super_construct` only calls `g_object_new`.
- `my_derived_construct` only calls `my_super_construct` (which in turn calls `g_object_new`.

So everything is nicely chained by the Vala compiler and the C#/Java style constructors are translated into GObject-style construction.

As to the initialization of members: If you don't provide intialization in your Vala code the generated construct functions won't initialize anything as well.

All this is done behind the scenes for you with Vala. You shouldn't worry about the details of the code generation, but if you want you always can with `-C` ...